# Saving core data entries and they are not directly available for fetching, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In an effort to learn how to refactor etc I move all my core data and nsfetchcontrollers to two classes, one to manage all core data methods and one to handle all fetches. I have an issue where the last inputted data isn't visible unless I restart app or add more data.

I have two viewcontrollers, the first (A) that displays the data and the second (B) where the user can input data.

My core data class is a singleton, dataManager and my fetching class is called fetchManager. in ViewDidLoad of each viewController I do this:

```
dataManager = [XEPDataManager sharedInstance];
self.managedObjectContext = dataManager.managedObjectContext;
self.fetchManager = [[XEPResultFetchedController alloc] initWithContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

then in A I perform a fetch in viewWillAppear and display the amount of data.

```
1. NSLog(@"Count: %i", [[fetchManager fetch] count]);
```

in B I create a new entity and before I go back to A i perform a save in viewWillDisappear.

```
2. 
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

I am experiencing something like this:

1. Starting app
2. Viewing A
3. Count: 0
4. Go to B, input data then back to A.
5. Count: 0 (expected 1)
6. Repeat step 4
7. Count: 1 (expected 2)
8. Restarts app
   9: Count: 2
   10: Repeat step 4
   11: Count: 2

So obviously the data is saved.. but somehow not directly and I first thought it was something with me juggling the contexts that when I assign a "local version" (unsure if this is how it works). I tried update the context in my fetch manager with the one in my singleton dataManager before I fetched in viewDidAppear but with no luck.

Anyone have any idea what it can be?

Comment: `before I go back to A`. Which methods are the fetch and save in (`viewWillAppear:` / `viewDidAppear:` / `viewWillDisappear:` / something else) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add that. I fetch in viewDidAppear and save in viewWillDisappear

Comment: Are you using thread confinement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that save on a context is async. When it's finished you get a notification. Proper way to do it would be to implement delegate methods of nsfetchcontroller. This way you will get a callback when something happens and you can update UI accordingly.

Comment: Ah, this could explain everything. Since there only should be a couple of ms between my save and my fetch. Will try implement the delegate methods and some kind of listener that have to redraw the ui.